# cannot resolve symbol `SetCapability`

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, appium

I am trying to use appium to do some automated testing. I have downloaded and added the jar's from

- Selenium-server-4.3.0
- Selenium-java-4.3.0
- lang3
- java 8.1.1

[image: Image of error]
Seen above importing of the packages have no issue but the method of the `setCapability` does not work. I've checked the implementation / defining that it exists and the method works. I've tried various methods of fixing `cannot reference symbol` but none worked. I also tried opening the folder in Android studio and the error also exists. If more information is required please feel free to comment. thank you!

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Doing this outside a method is not valid Java - you have to use `setCapability` inside a test method or ideally in a `@Before*` annotated method executed before your test methods. Example:

```
@BeforeClass
public void setCapabilities() {
  dc.setCapability("browserVersion", "10.0");
}
```